# XLOOKUP function is failing

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlookup

I'm trying to use xlookup function to get the corresponding values, if the certain text is matching. Following is the example, trying to use. If not right function, would you please point to the right one?

Function:

```
=XLOOKUP("*"&D1&"*",A1:A4,B1:B4,"Not found",2)
```

Any support in this regard is really appreciated!

Below is the table in excel:

[image]

Comment: Well, they're not matching. What do you expect? What should be a match in your example and why?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! As mentioned, I wanted to see if one of the text(string) is matching, it should return the values of the B column. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please use an example that's closer to your real data? It seems that you want to do a wild card search of all the keywords in column D in column A, and as soon as there is a match, you want to return the corresponding value in column B. May I know what if the keywords are appearing more than once in Column A, which value to return? In addition, is the match case sensitive or not?

Comment: You mean any of the **separated** strings in column D? Any, or both?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The following function works =XLOOKUP("*"&TEXTBEFORE(D1,",")&"*",$A$1:$A$4,$B$1:$B$4,"Not Found",2)

Comment: I doubt mentioned function works. It only looks for the first comma separated string of `D1` also your example shows mixed lower and upper case. Does that make a difference? And as asked before, Would both comma separated strings in D have to match both space separated string in A? Should it ignore lower/upper case?

Comment: Its working! As, I have mentioned. However, there is different use-case, which also wanted to consider i.e., use-case: ABC DEF EGF(A column) -- ABC DEFEGF(D column). Thanks!

Comment: @P.b You are correct. Actually we have to sort words in each cell both for column A and column D, then match entire cell virtually inside formula. Formula would be little bit complex and bigger.

Comment: @Harun24hr see my answer. But with Sudhir's last comment that doesn't make any sense anymore. No comma separation, no space separation in D. Why and how is that considered a match?
I also doubt he wants to lookup from D to A, or the other way around, since no expected results are shared. The issue is a nice one, the question should be improved a lot though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your case correctly you're trying to search for a case sensitive match of both comma separated strings in column D to match the space separated strings in column A and return the value of column B for the matching row.

For a single line search you could use:
`=FILTER(B$1:B$5,MMULT(--ISNUMBER(FIND(" "&TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(", "&D$1:D$5,", ",{1,2}),", ")&" "," "&A1&" ")),{1;1})=2,"Not found")`

For spilling the results for a range you could use:

```
=LET(A, A1:A5,
     B, B1:B5,
     D, D1:D5,
     s, " ",
MAP(A,LAMBDA(M,FILTER(B,MMULT(--ISNUMBER(FIND(s&TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(", "&D,", ",{1,2}),", ")&s,s&M&s)),{1;1})=2,"Not found"))))
```

This formula works if both comma separatedstrings of `D1:D5` have a (case sensitive) match to the space separated strings in `A1:A5`.

[image]

Or another way:

```
=LET(A,MAP(A1:A5,LAMBDA(m,CONCAT(SORT(TEXTSPLIT(m,," ")&"|")))),
     D,MAP(D1:D5,LAMBDA(m,CONCAT(SORT(TEXTSPLIT(m,,", ")&"|")))),
BYROW(EXACT(A,TRANSPOSE(D)),LAMBDA(r,FILTER(TOROW(B1:B5),r,"not found"))))
```

If it could be more than two separated strings, change it to:

```
=LET(A, A1:A6,
     B, B1:B6,
     D, D1:D6,
     s, " ",
MAP(A,LAMBDA(M,LET(n,ROWS(TEXTSPLIT(M,," ")),FILTER(B,MMULT(--ISNUMBER(FIND(s&TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(", "&D,", ",SEQUENCE(,n)),", ")&s,s&M&s)),SEQUENCE(n,,,0))=n,"Not found")))))
```

and

```
=LET(A,MAP(A1:A6,LAMBDA(m,CONCAT(SORT(TEXTSPLIT(m,," ")&"|")))),
     D,MAP(D1:D6,LAMBDA(m,CONCAT(SORT(TEXTSPLIT(m,,", ")&"|")))),
BYROW(EXACT(A,TRANSPOSE(D)),LAMBDA(r,FILTER(TOROW(B1:B6),r,"not found"))))
```

Comment: See edit for if there's more than 2 possible separated strings to search (I think that's what you were aiming at in the comments).

Answer (score 1):

Use partial match either before comma or after comma. Try-

```
=XLOOKUP("*"&TEXTBEFORE(D1,",")&"*",$A$1:$A$4,$B$1:$B$4,"Not Found",2)
```

[image]

Comment: One more use-case, Sorry for the extension of this! I also would like to have following use-case: ABC DEF EGF(A column) -- ABC DEFEGF(D column). Basically, I wanted to match to anyone of the string. Thanks!

Comment: We have to use different approach then.